# How to find a object in list with columns in c#

Tags: c#

My name is Thiago! I'm studing C#. and i need make a exercise that search a object in a list with partition (columns).

C# version 4.5.2
Visual Studio 2017

The list:

```
alunosMatriculados.Add(new Aluno { matAluno = 2, nomeAluno = "MARIANA DA SILVA", cpfAluno = "111.111.111-12", turmaAluno = "2I", numFaltas = 0 });
alunosMatriculados.Add(new Aluno { matAluno = 3, nomeAluno = "ANA MARIA SILVEIRA", cpfAluno = "111.111.111-13", turmaAluno = "1H", numFaltas = 5 });
alunosMatriculados.Add(new Aluno { matAluno = 4, nomeAluno = "ROBERTO LINS", cpfAluno = "111.111.111-14", turmaAluno = "3H", numFaltas = 1 });
```

Ok. The problem is "Search something in the list that the user insert"

I tried:

```
string name;

 Console.WriteLine("Student's name");
    name = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine(alunosMatriculados.Find(x => x.nomeAluno.Contains(name)));
```

the var `name` is the student's name
`nomeAluno` is the student's name (I'm brazilian...)

Someone help me please!

Comment: So what's the issue you are facing with this code? What output should be generated and what output you are getting with this code?

Comment: I need that all line data to be shown according to the student's name.

ex: When the user enters 'Mariana da Silva', an enrollment (matAluno), CPF (cpfaluno), a class (student class) and as student absences (numFaltas)

Comment: That's what you need. What issue you are facing with the code?

Comment: When I tried this code: string name;

 Console.WriteLine("Student's name");
    name = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine(alunosMatriculados.Find(x => x.nomeAluno.Contains(name)));

Comment: The output is ProjectName.ClassName

Comment: I don't know why don't work. Really

Comment: The full code is https://dotnetfiddle.net/J5D6jn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `List<T>.Find` returns `T` as the result, and `Console.WriteLine` will print the object's `.ToString()` as the output. The result is that it prints `Aluno.ToString()`, which is class name by default. I would write it like

```
Aluno a = alunosMatriculados.Find(x => x.nomeAluno.Contains(name));
if (a != null) 
{
     // ... Whatever you want to do with 
}
else Console.WriteLine("Not found");
```

This way, we cover the case that there might not be any item that matches our condition. However, there are still cases that there might be more than one item that matches, and I suggest you lookup for how to use LINQ's `Where` and `foreach` so you can print all matched items.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my idea:

```
    class Aluno
    {
        public int matAluno { get; set; }
        public string nomeAluno { get; set; }
        public string cpfAluno { get; set; }
        public string turmaAluno { get; set; }
        public int numFaltas { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var alunosMatriculados = new List<Aluno>();
        alunosMatriculados.Add(new Aluno { matAluno = 2, nomeAluno = "MARIANA DA SILVA", cpfAluno = "111.111.111-12", turmaAluno = "2I", numFaltas = 0 });
        alunosMatriculados.Add(new Aluno { matAluno = 3, nomeAluno = "ANA MARIA SILVEIRA", cpfAluno = "111.111.111-13", turmaAluno = "1H", numFaltas = 5 });
        alunosMatriculados.Add(new Aluno { matAluno = 4, nomeAluno = "ROBERTO LINS", cpfAluno = "111.111.111-14", turmaAluno = "3H", numFaltas = 1 });

        foreach(var aluno in FindByName(alunosMatriculados, "SIL"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(aluno.nomeAluno);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static IEnumerable<Aluno> FindByName( IEnumerable<Aluno> alunos, string partOfName )
    {
        //TODO error handling 
        //TODO use brazilian culture, if needed
        return  alunos
            .Where(a => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.nomeAluno))
            .Where(a => a.nomeAluno.Contains(partOfName));
    }

    static Aluno FindFirstByName(IEnumerable<Aluno> alunos, string name)
    {
        return FindByName(alunos, name)?.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Comment: Wow. it's intense. I'm learning yet... could explain: static Aluno FindFirstByName(IEnumerable<Aluno> alunos, string name)
    {
        return FindByName(alunos, name)?.FirstOrDefault();
    }